# Emeditor: run a macro for all file inside a folder?

Tags: emeditor

How to run a (previously recorded) macro for all files inside a folder ?

Example : I have recorded a macro that is working correctly for an opened html file. I have saved the macro as "test.jsee".
I have a folder in my computer named "C:\folder_with_files". It is full of html files.
How to run "test.jsee" for all files inside the folder "C:\folder_with_files" ?

ps: same question if many subfolders contains html files inside the main big folder "C:\folder_with_files" ?

pps: my idea is that Emeditor opens one file, run the macro, close the file (I have already saved the updated file in my macro) and do the same for the next file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to accomplish your task.

1. Select `Run with Temporary Options` on the `Macros` menu. Select the macro, set the `Run the macro against each opened document` option, add (or drag and drop) files or folders to the list, and set the `Save and close each document after running the macro` if necessary.

Or

2. Select `Advanced Open` on the `File` menu. Set the `Run a macro against each opened document`, select the macro, click the `Select Files to Open...` button to select all files you want to open.

Or

3. Run a macro using JScript with `Scripting.FileSystemObject`. Your old macro should be written as a function (in this case, `MyFunc`):

```
#language = "JScript"

function MyFunc( sFileName )   // macro function to call
{
    document.writeln( sFileName );  // Replace this with what you want to do with sFileName
}

sFolder = "C:\\folder_with_files";   // a folder you want to search

fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
f = fso.GetFolder(sFolder);
fc = new Enumerator(f.files);
for (; !fc.atEnd(); fc.moveNext()) {
    MyFunc( fc.item().name );
}
```

If you can't see these commands, please make sure you are using the newest version of EmEditor Professional.

Comment: Fantastic. Many thanks. ;)

Comment: is there a command line version of this?

Comment: @Jon No, but you can write a macro to iterate all files inside a folder if you use a command line.

Comment: is there an example?  Or a link to an example of how this command line version is done?  for a single file or for multiple files inside a folder.   The help files often lack real life examples, so it can be difficult to follow along.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please use the method 3.